# GetElementByTagName not working correctly inside iframe pop-up when trying to add UTM parameters

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Trying to dynamically append UTM parameters to outbound URLs on a page.  There are two locations where this needs to happen - a traditional outbound URL in body and a URL housed in a button on a pop-up that displays 5 seconds after page load.

The code I wrote to append the UTM parameter is working perfectly on the traditional URL, but for the life of me I can't get it to select the href inside the pop-up and append it on.

For context, the iframe loads immediately, but I have a Customer Trigger set-up inside GTM to fire every 2500 seconds to fix an issue I had earlier with declaring element visibility.

Here is the code I have to search the site for URLs where the domain is the outbound link and to append on the UTM parameter if a GCLID cookie is present:

```
(function() {
  var utmInheritingDomains = [
    "outboundURL.com" // Replace this domain
  ],

  utmRegExp = /(\&|\?)utm_[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+/gi,
  iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"),
  links = iframe.document.getElementsByClassName("hb-cta.undefined"),
  utms = [
    "aff_click_id={{GCLID Cookie}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE utm_medium
  ];

  for (var index2 = 0; index2 < links.length; index2 += 1) {
    for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index += 1) {
      var tempLink = links[index].href,
      tempParts;
      if (tempLink.indexOf(utmInheritingDomains[index2]) > 0) { // The script is looking for all links with the utmInheritingDomain
        tempLink = tempLink.replace(utmRegExp, "");
        tempParts = tempLink.split("#");

        if (tempParts[0].indexOf("?") < 0 ) {
          tempParts[0] += "?" + utms.join("&"); // The script adds UTM parameters to all links with the domain you've defined
        } else {
          tempParts[0] += "&" + utms.join("&");
        }
        tempLink = tempParts.join("#");
      }
      links[index].href = tempLink;
    }
  }
}());
```

And here is the code for the target URL in question...

```html
<a id="hb-traffic-cta" class="hb-cta undefined" 
   onclick="if (hellobar('base.preview').isActive()) {
       return false
     } else {
       hellobar('elements.conversion')
         .trackClick(
           this,
           hellobar('elements').findById(717066)
         ); 
       return true
     };" 
   href="https://OUTBOUNDURL.com/" target="_blank" style="...">...</a>
```

Comment: My guess is you need `iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]` since that method returns an HTMLCollection, even if there's just a single one.

Comment: Tried that earlier hoping it would resolve it, but did not

Comment: `iframe.document.getElementsByClassName` should be throwing an error that tells you something. You should also post the error.

Comment: What is the URL of the `iframe` relative to the main window? If they are on different origins, you may be constrained by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)